# Form in bootstrap modal

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on a web app where users can modify mysql table data from it.
In the first section I have a button called "Ajout donées", when you click on it a form apear to add data in bdd_sites table. I try unsuccefully to add this form in a modal for design purposes.

The form and modal does appear but nothing append when I click on button send (called "Envoyer" in my code). Also nothing appear on the window network in the inspector. As if no request had been sent

Here is my form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="bddModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="bddModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="bddModalLabel">Ajout donées</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <form action="" id="myForm" method="POST"></form>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="nom">Nom</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nom" maxlength="100">
                    <span>Enter un nom</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="categorie">catégorie</label>
                    <select name="categorie" id="cat-select">
                        <option value="1">Fiscalité IS</option>
                        <option value="2">Réorganisations, acquisitions et méthodologie</option>
                        <option value="3">Contrôle et contentieux fiscal</option>
                        <option value="4">Fiscalité patrimoniale</option>
                        <option value="5">Fiscalité Immobilière</option>
                        <option value="6">Introduction à la TVA et droits de douanes</option>
                        <option value="7">Excel</option>
                    </select>
                    <span>Choissisez une catégorie</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="url">Url</label>
                    <input type="text" name="url">
                    <span>Entrer une url</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="img">Image</label>
                    <input type="text" name="img">
                    <span>Enter l'adresse d'une image</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">
        </div>
    </form>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Later in my code I have a condition that checks post requests:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
```

Concerning my current problem, I check the presence of a url, specific field of the form with the id "myForm" (of which I have shown the code above)

```
 else if(isset($_POST['url'])) {
                                var_dump("Je suis dans l'action AJOUTE de la partie bases de donnees");
                                $nom= $_POST['nom'];
                                $categorie= $_POST['categorie'];
                                $url= $_POST['url'];
                                $img= $_POST['img'];
                                $sql= "INSERT INTO bdd_sites (nom, categorie, url, img) VALUES ('$nom','$categorie','$url',' $img');";
                                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                            }
```

Comment: Can you check the Network tab of your Dev Tools in the browser to see the request list? If so, can you tell me whether a new entry appears when you click on the button in the popup?

Comment: Are you using `Javascript` to submit your data to the backend? because your form `<form action="" id="myForm" method="POST">` doesn't contain `action`. And if youre using `JS`, show your `JS` code.

Comment: @IbrahimHammed it could be a self-post

Comment: Nothing appear in Network when I click on the button to submit my form